# In bash, how can I have a set of arguments in any random order? Like a key-value pair?

Tags: bash

**Example:**

```
./myscript --ip 192.168.1.1 --port 1985
```

**or another possible**

```
./myscript --port 1985 --ip 192.168.1.1
```

**I want to allow my script to take a set of arguments, in any order**

```
./myscript a b c d
./myscript d c b a
./myscript b d a c
```

Etcetera

Comment: Usually, IP and port are specified in a single argument: `192.168.1.1:1985`

Comment: @mouviciel I would agree but this is just for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

take a look at [`getopts`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial)

> **getopts**: getopts optstring name [arg]
>      Parse option arguments.
>
> Getopts is used by shell procedures to parse positional parameters
>       as options.
>
> *`OPTSTRING`* contains the option letters to be recognized; if a letter
>       is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument,
>       which should be separated from it by white space.
>
> Each time it is invoked, getopts will place the next option in the
>       shell variable $name, initializing name if it does not exist, and
>       the index of the next argument to be processed into the shell
>       variable OPTIND.  OPTIND is initialized to 1 each time the shell or
>       a shell script is invoked.  When an option requires an argument,
>       getopts places that argument into the shell variable *`OPTARG`*.
>
> getopts reports errors in one of two ways.  If the first character
>       of OPTSTRING is a colon, getopts uses silent error reporting.  In
>       this mode, no error messages are printed.  If an invalid option is
>       seen, getopts places the option character found into OPTARG.  If a
>       required argument is not found, getopts places a '**:**' into NAME and
>       sets OPTARG to the option character found.  If getopts is not in
>       silent mode, and an invalid option is seen, getopts places '?' into
>       NAME and unsets OPTARG.  If a required argument is not found, a '**?**'
>       is placed in NAME, OPTARG is unset, and a diagnostic message is
>       printed.
>
> If the shell variable *`OPTERR`* has the value 0, getopts disables the
>       printing of error messages, even if the first character of
>       OPTSTRING is not a colon.  OPTERR has the value 1 by default.
>
> Getopts normally parses the positional parameters ($0 - $9), but if
>       more arguments are given, they are parsed instead.
>
> *Exit Status*:
>      Returns success if an option is found; fails if the end of options is
>       encountered or an error occurs.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `getopts` to parse command-line arguments. [This tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) is quite useful to get started with.

Answer (score 6):

This simple script takes the port number with `p` and ip address with `i` parameter.

```
while getopts "i:p:" option; do
  case $option in
    i ) ip_address=$OPTARG
    echo "ip address: $ip_address"
    ;;
    p ) port_number=$OPTARG
    echo "port number: $port_number"
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Can be executed in either ways:

`./myscript -i 192.168.1.1 -p 1985`

or

`./myscript -p 1985 -i 192.168.1.1`

When executed it prints:

```
ip address: 192.168.1.1
port number: 1985
```

Also as mentioned at http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

> Note that getopts is not able to parse GNU-style long options (--myoption) or XF86-style long options (-myoption)

So you cannot use long strings as `--port` or `--ip` directly with `getopts`.
However additional workarounds available as described in this link:
http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt